# Does virtual inheritance have a cost when it isn't really needed or used?

Tags: c++

If I do the following:

```
class Derived : public virtual Base {};
```

But `Base` never occurs twice for the same descendent class, is there still a cost? In other words, does simply adding the keyword introduce that extra level of indirection for any virtual function call between `Base` and subclasses of `Derived`? Or is it the appearance of `Base` twice or more from the perspective of a descendent class that triggers it?

The wording on this is a bit tough... I hope that my question makes sense.

Comment: If Base has fields, every access to the Base fields from Derived will cost since the compiler needs to find Base from a shift index stored in the virtual method table. This is also the case for every cast from Derived to Base. Moreover every cast from Base to Derived is a `dynamic_cast` which is more costly than a `static_cast`.

Comment: @Franck Is this true even if you are using a `Derived` instance directly? I.e. no weird diamond inheritance.

Comment: Yes it is true since the class Derived cannot know if a future Derived2 class (in another translation unit) will not create a diamond. In such a case the shift from Derived* to Base* would be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Derived` is `final` then the compiler can devirtualize the inheritance from `Base`; however, there is no guarantee that it *will*, and the platform ABI may preclude its doing so.

If `Derived` is not `final`, the compiler has to anticipate that a `Derived` could be a subobject of a complete object that has another `Base`:

```
class MoreDerived : public virtual Base, public Derived {};
```

The compiler may also be able to devirtualize the inheritance of `Derived` from `Base` during link-time optimization, if it can observe that `Derived` never occurs as a subobject; but again, there is no guarantee that it will do so.